# C - Append strings until end of allocated memory

Tags: c, string, memory, append, concatenation

Let's consider following piece of code:

```
int len = 100;
char *buf = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*len);
printf("Appended: %s\n",struct_to_string(some_struct,buf,len));
```

Someone allocated amount of memory in order to get it filled with string data. The problem is that string data taken from some_struct could be ANY length. So what i want to achieve is to make struct_to_string function do the following:

1. Do not allocate any memory that goes outside (so, buf has to be allocated outside of the function, and passed)
2. Inside the struct_to_string I want to do something like:

   ```
   char* struct_to_string(const struct type* some_struct, char* buf, int len) {

   //it will be more like pseudo code to show the idea :) 


   char var1_name[] = "int l1";
   buf += var1_name + " = " + some_struct->l1; 
   //when l1 is a int or some non char, I need to cast it 

   char var2_name[] = "bool t1";
   buf += var2_name + " = " + some_struct->t1; 

   // buf+= (I mean appending function) should check if there is a place in a buf,
   //if there is not it should fill buf with
   //as many characters as possible (without writting to memory) and stop
   //etc.

   return buf;
   }
   ```

Output should be like:

```
Appended: int l1 = 10 bool t1 = 20  //if there was good amount of memory allocated or
ex: Appended: int l1 = 10 bo //if there was not enough memory allocated
```

To sum up:

1. I need a function (or couple of functions) that adds given strings to the base string without overwritting base string;
2. do nothing when base string memory is full
3. I can not use C++ libraries

Another things that I could ask but are not so important right now:

1. Is there a way (in C) iterate through structure variable list to get their names, or at least to get their values without their names? (for example iterate through structure like through array ;d)

I do not normally use C, but for now I'm obligated to do, so I have very basic knowledge.
(sorry for my English)

Edit:

Good way to solve that problem is shown in post below: stackoverflow.com/a/2674354/2630520

Comment: Don't cast the return of `malloc`, and `char` is guaranteed to be 1 in size, so `char *buf = malloc(len);` will do. Also: `buf += var1_name + " = " + some_struct->l1;`... does that even compile?? What warnings are you seeing?

Comment: `int plen = snprintf(buf, len, "%s = %d%s = %d", var1_name, some_struct->l1, var2_name, some_struct->t1); if (plen >= len) Handle_NotEnough()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically I did it like here:  stackoverflow.com/a/2674354/2630520

```
int struct_to_string(const struct struct_type* struct_var, char* buf, const int len)
{
    unsigned int length = 0;
    unsigned int i;

    length += snprintf(buf+length, len-length, "v0[%d]",  struct_var->v0);
    length += other_struct_to_string(struct_var->sub, buf+length, len-length);
    length += snprintf(buf+length, len-length, "v2[%d]", struct_var->v2);
    length += snprintf(buf+length, len-length, "v3[%d]", struct_var->v3);
    ....

    return length;
}
```

`snprintf` writes as much as possible and discards everything left, so it was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say all you need is the standard `strncat` function defined in the string.h header.

About the *'iterate through structure variable list'* part, I'm not exactly sure what you mean. If your talking about iterating over the structure's **members**, a short answer would be : you can't introspect C structs for free.

You need to know beforehand what structure type you're using so that the compiler know at what *offset* in the memory it can find each member of your struct. Otherwise it's just an array of bytes like any other.

Don't mind asking if I wasn't clear enough or if you want more details.
Good luck.